# Different results of localeAwareCompare

Tags: android, c++, qt

I need to compare two UTF-8 encoded strings containing macron characters (Ā, Ō, Ū). The order should be A < Ā < O < Ō < U < Ū meaning that the macron characters should not be compared based on their numeric value (A < O < U < Ā < Ō < Ū), but lexicographically.

In order to achieve this, I tried using [localeAwareCompare](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#localeAwareCompare-1):

```
QString a = QString::fromUtf8("Ā");
QString b = QString::fromUtf8("O");
int result = QString::localeAwareCompare(a, b);
```

With this piece of code I am encountering different behavior on my desktop computer running Mac OS and android. On the desktop computer, the result is -1 (which is correct, because Ā < O) while android yields 117 (which is incorrect).

The Qt documentation for [localeAwareCompare](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#localeAwareCompare-1) contains the following remark:

```
The comparison is performed in a locale- and also platform-dependent manner.
```

The default locales on the devices I am using are:

- Mac OS:

  - Name: en_US
  - Script: 7
  - Country: UnitedStates
- Android:

  - Name: ""
  - Script: 0
  - Country: AnyCountry

Manually setting the default locale to en_US does not help. My only guess is that this is due to the platform dependency.

I am at a loss here. Is this behaviour supposed to be correct? If so, is there another option to compute the desired comparison?

---

**Example**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString a = QString::fromUtf8("A");
    QString a_m = QString::fromUtf8("Ā");
    QString o = QString::fromUtf8("O");

    qDebug() << (QString::localeAwareCompare(a, a_m) < 0 ? "A < Ā" : "Ā < A");
    qDebug() << (QString::localeAwareCompare(a_m, o) < 0 ? "Ā < O" : "O < Ā");

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773914/why-isnt-qstringlocaleawarecompare-working-correctly) shows that some Qt versions appear to be broken. I tested your example with Qt 4.8.6 as well as Qt 5.2.1, and got different results.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.5.1. What do you mean with "different results"? Do you get the correct result Ā < O?

Comment: Hm, to be fair I always seem to get −1 on Qt5, but I get −79 on Qt4 unless I add a `QLocale::setDefault()` statement. If I add that, I get −1 on Qt4 as well. But my code is probably also different from yours. Can you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Some websites which may be useful: https://wiki.qt.io/Locale_Support_in_Qt_5#Android and http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: The question now contains an example.

Comment: thanks. In Ubuntu Linux, see the correct result with all Qt versions I have (A < Ā < O). So unfortunately I cannot tell you anything except that I can confirm it works on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you run it on android as well?

Comment: Only Ubuntu. Sorry if that was not clear. But that at least confirms that your code is working in principle. to me, that looks like your problem is definitely Android-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the macrons by de-composing the string:

```
QString a = QString::fromUtf8("Ā");
QString norm = a.normalized(QString::NormalizationForm_D);
QString aOut;
// Remove all marks
Q_FOREACH(QChar ch, norm){
    QChar::Category c = ch.category();
    if (c != QChar::Mark_Enclosing &&
        c != QChar::Mark_NonSpacing &&
        c != QChar::Mark_SpacingCombining){
            aOut.append(ch);
    }
}
qDebug() << aOut; // prints "A"
```

Then compare the strings normally. However, this will also break graphemes such as Æ. A more sophisticated algorithm will be needed to avoid that.

For reference: 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#normalized